# Jenkins - How to run - docker system prune - in the pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This is my Jenkinsfile for building docker image and pushing it to dockerhub. Everything works just great. 
I would like to clean up the untagged images after the build process. Currently I do `docker system prune -f` manually on the Jenkins node. Is there anyway to incorporate when agent is `none`?

```
pipeline {
    agent none  
    stages {
        stage('Build Jar') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3.6.0'
                    args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean package'
            }
        }
        stage('Build Image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    app = docker.build("myimagename")
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Push Image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    app.push("latest")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do a raw shell command for it; that works. Would recommend doing it in a `post` as part of a cleanup though and not directly in/during the pipeline inside the agent `none` like you suggested.

Comment: @MattSchuchard is correct. I currently do this and it works fine. `sh"docker system prune -f"` is all you need.

Comment: Is it safe to run docker prune in Jenkins? Isn't there the risk to break some other CI/CD already in progress?